# Android Studio : Vector drawable (SVG) not supporting font

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, svg, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to use my logo which is made by me with the help of Adobe illustrator for my Android App, but I am getting error. The font (Arial Black) I used in the logo is not supported (text not supported) while using it as my launcher icon in android studio.
I tried to solve the error with previous stack overflow answers and some google blogs but could not help myself.
Any help will be highly appreciated.[See My Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdbOq.png)

[Here is the error shown in Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB8CE.png)

Comment: Make its svg file then import as drawable it will not ask for font.

Comment: @HusnainQasim thanks for your answer but i did make it in SVG file format and it's showing error, text not supported.

Comment: Ok try it in 2 steps 1st import SVG as Vector asset not as Image Asset 2nd Now make Image Asset with that imported Vector. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: @HusnainQasim tried that too, still says <text> is not supported :(

Comment: Could you post a link to your SVG or open it with a text editor and paste the info here?

Comment: @OmarSilva Sure, here it is, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nFwWPEudQsqn2xLwVSCjlhSpfmhX1U1J

Comment: It looks like you need to expand your text in Illustrator before exporting it to .svg or choose `convert to outline` during exporting.

Comment: @OmarSilva Thanks a lot brother, expanded the text in illustrator and it worked.